# Unable to start Genymotion - unable to initialize the subwindow system

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm trying to get into developing Android apps, and whilst the Google android emulator works, it's incredibly slow.

following another answer here on stackoverflow, it was recommended to give genymotion a go.

Well, I've got it all installed, but it wont start any device.

Instead, all I get is a black window and then shortly after the following error message:

[image]

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I tried to use Genymotion on Ubuntu 14.04. At first, it worked, but it did not the next day and gave the same error message. I didn't find a fix for it directly, though I think the problem was because of the AMD Catalyst driver that I was trying to install for my HD7790. 
If you also use ATI driver and Ubuntu 14.04, this may help you:

https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/Diag/MissingLibGL#u1404amd

I reinstalled Ubuntu, and did step 4, 5, and 6 in the AMD section.

This solve some issues that I had with the driver from AMD website:
- QtCreator : libgl, something with swrast driver
- Computer freezes during suspend
- Genymotion unable to initialize subwindow system.