# Genymotion error when rotating android screen

Tags: android, genymotion

When I run my application, it runs perfectly. But when I press the "Rotate Screen" button, i get this error message:[image: Erroe]

It says: "Unable to start the virtual device" and "Unable to initialize the subwindow system"

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513578/unable-to-start-genymotion-unable-to-initialize-the-subwindow-system

Comment: It doesn't help. I have the latest AMD catalyst drivers on my computer and running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You mean,you want a horizontal Screen? If not ,try this to lock the screen.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.hf.yuguo.home.TabActivityHome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```